# Join 3 tables and filter

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, join

I am having trouble with my school project. First off, I have to make a big join and put that in a virtual table and use it later on.

Next, I want to make something where I join 3 tables and use WHERE clause to filter by date.
But I don't know how to filter a date for a range i.e.:

```
Date1= 2:40 PM Date 2 = 3:40 PM, IF date1 [is in range of 1 hour with] Date2
```

I have made a picture to make it more clear.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/CSZSD22.png]

Comment: Your picture did not make it more clear.  The text within it is unreadable.  Regarding the part about dates, what is the datatype for the date1 and date2 column.

Comment: Sorry for the picture and the date1 and date2 are both time without timestamp

Comment: You've show the select clause and the where clause, but it is not clear where you are stuck on making the joins. I suggest you post the SQL that you are using.

Comment: i dont know how to think, it keeps giving mme the error that the column name doesnt excist

Comment: We *very much* prefer text over images. One cannot copy paste from a picture. An image *may* sometimes be useful *additionally*. I suggest you [cooperate with your fellow students here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997953/query-combining-3-tables) to produce a single, proper question. And show us what you tried, even if it's not working.

Comment: Storing separate time and date is a really bad idea. If you want to store "a certain time on a particular data" you should *always* use a timestamp type. Then you can just use the `BETWEEN` operator to compare them.