# Query combining 3 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm stuck with my school project. We have 3 tables:

```
filteredtweets(Place, SoortOV, Comment, Time, Date), 
rooster(Lesid, Timestart, Timeend), 
student(studentid, woonplaats, vervoersmiddel)
```

We want a list with this select statement, but I guess something is wrong:

```
SELECT student.studentid, student.woonplaats, rooster.Lesid, 
filteredtweets.SoortOV, filteredtweets.Date, filteredtweets.Comment
```

and we need to have the results based on 2 `WHERE` clauses:

```
WHERE filteredtweets.Place = student.woonplaats
WHERE filteredtweets.Time [is 30 minutes in range of] rooster.Timestart
```

[Here is the screenshot of our database in PostgreSQL.](http://prntscr.com/38sw4r)

Comment: Post the entire query you're using and the error you're receiving. Make sure you are using `AND` where appropriate...

Comment: I can't see any relationship from your screenshot and explanation.  Can you be more clear on how these three tables are mapped?  (Perhaps studentId is found in filteredtweets, etc)?

Comment: we dont have any query atm

Comment: ok reuploaded the screenshot

Comment: @user3511678 You must try to write a query yourself first.

Comment: @user3511678 Then show us the queries you tried and we will try to help you with them.

Comment: Your question cannot be answered, since you do not describe what you need. Also, we very much prefer text over screenshots. One cannot copy/paste tesxt from images. Provide table definitions like you get from psql with `\d tbl`.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993907/join-3-tables-and-filter

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could probably use an introductory SQL course.

It looks like your database design is completely off. In order to do anything useful, you need some way of linking the tables togethers. Look into the concepts `Primary Key` and `Foreign Key`.

I'm guessing - I don't know because you didn't specify what you need - that you are looking for something like the query below. For this query I assume that a table student_les exists that links a `student` to a `rooster`, and that filteredtweets has a column `studentid`, so that we know which student sent this tweet.

Unfortunately the `WHERE` Clauses you specified yourself don't seem to make any sense, so I left them out. Again, you didn't specify what you need, so I can't say for sure.

```
SELECT student.studentid, student.woonplaats, rooster.Lesid, 
filteredtweets.SoortOV, filteredtweets.Date, filteredtweets.Comment
FROM student, rooster, filteredTweets, student_les
WHERE student.lesId = student_Les.lesId
AND student_les.lesId = rooster.lesId
AND filteredtweets.studentid = student.studentid
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
SELECT
  s.studentid,
  s.woonplaats,
  s.Lesid,
  f.SoortOV,
  f.Date,
  f.Comment 
 FROM
  filteredtweets f 
  INNER JOIN
      rooster r 
       ON f.Time >= r.Timestart::TIMESTAMP + (30 || ' minutes')::interval 
       OR f.Time <= r.Timestart::TIMESTAMP + (30 || ' minutes')::interval 
 INNER JOIN
     student s 
       ON f.Place = s.woonplaats
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//s.tk/meta/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!